# Kivy TextInput on_double_tap

Tags: text, widget, kivy

I have added a text input window to my Kivy APP and I am trying to do two things with the window. The text input window by default highlights words that are double clicked. I want to store that word to a variable and cant figure out how to pass it from the input window to a variabel. Secondly, I am trying to cut and paste from the OS into Kivy and cannot figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the code I have so far. Thanks goes out to Inclement for helping me get this far.

```
Builder.load_string('''

<MouseWidget>:
    image: image
    label: label
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Image:
        id: image
        source: root.source
    Label:
        id: label
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        text: 'Test'
''')

class MouseWidget(BoxLayout):
    image = ObjectProperty()
    label = ObjectProperty()
    source = StringProperty()


    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.image.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            trigger = 0
            if touch.x >= 133 and touch.x <= 646 and touch.y >= 162 and touch.y <=675:
            self.label.text = str(touch.pos)


    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        self.label.text = 'This is a test'



class TESTApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Accordion(orientation='horizontal')

        item= AccordionItem(title='Test')
        src = "image.png"
        image = MouseWidget(source=src, size_hint = (1.0, 1.0))

        textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world', size_hint = (0.5, 1.0))
        textinput.bind(text2 = on_double_tap())


        # add image to AccordionItem
        item.add_widget(image)
        item.add_widget(textinput)
        root.add_widget(item)

    return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TESTApp().run()
```

Comment: Is this the same code you are testing with? There is no TextInput in this code.

Comment: Qua-non, I had the text input box displaying on the screen but until you wrote the code below I didn't know how to capture the text input. I am finding the learning curve for kivy difficult which is counter-intuitive because it is set up to make things easy. I guess it just hasn't clicked yet. Thanks for the help, your code below works brilliantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override your `on_double_tap` method like below.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.clock import Clock


class Test(TextInput):

    def on_double_tap(self):
        # make sure it performs it's original function
        super(Test, self).on_double_tap()

        def on_word_selection(*l):
            selected_word = self.selection_text
            print selected_word
            # do what you want with selected word here

        # let the word be selected wait for
        # next frame and get the selected word
        Clock.schedule_once(on_word_selection)

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

For copy and pasting TextInput supports ctrl + x,c,v, internally TextInput uses [_cut, _copy and _paste functions](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/textinput.py#L1055). You shouldn't need to use them directly kivy takes care of this for you just use ctrl + c, x, v.

Comment: qua-non, when you set the original text of the text input such as using the line textinput = Test(text='Hello world', size_hint = (0.5, 1.0)) is there a way to reset the text input box with new text? I want the text in the text input to change when I click the mouse in the MouseWidget class. Can I access the  text box from there?